# Trying to better understand the (<*>) function of Applicative functors in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I just finished chapter 11 of the *Learn You A Haskell For Great Good* and I would like to have a better understanding of Applicative Functors before moving on. I have the following **ghci** code.

```
let a = Just (5+) -- Instead of mapping + to Just 5
let b = (3+) <$> a -- I imported Control.Applicative even though most of these modules are deprecated
let c = Just (3+) <*> a -- I expect this to be equivalent to b and :t b, :t c shows that they are the 'same'
a <*> Just 1 -- returns 6 as I expected
```

Now I expect b and c to be: Just ((3+) . (5+)) which means that I could do:

```
b <*> Just 1 -- and get 9 as in (3+) $ (5+) 1 or ((3+) . (5+)) 1
```

But I get: **No instance for (Num (b0 -> b0)) arising from a use of 'it' In a stmt of an interactive GHCI command: print it**.

**Question 1:** what does the restriction as seen in the following imply:

```
b :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => Maybe (a -> a)
```

I thought that just means that <*> can "extract" the (a -> a) from 'b'. In my noob mind I know that **Num a** means that 'a' must be an instance of Num but **Num (a -> a)** is not making much sense to me. Does it mean that the (a -> b) inside the Maybe must return an instance of Num?

**Question 2:** Isn't everything I've done feasible in the Applicative realm? Is there any obvious ways to print or see the result of 'b <*> Just 1'?

```
let Just val = b <*> Just 1
:t val -- returns ((Num (t -> t), Num t) => t which tells me that val is an instance of Num but then again I am just a beginner so what do I know?
```

Note: I have snapshots of my ghci session and can add them if necessary. I read some related posts but nothing seems to enlighten me.

Comment: I just tried to put your first code lines into my ghci, but the declaration of b threw an error already. Maybe you should indicate the version of ghc you are using, and/or try to get the newest version first.

Comment: @Magnus GHCi, version 7.8.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you write (expanded)

```
let b = (3+) <$> Just (5+)
```

The resulting value, by definition of `<$>` (which is just `fmap`!) is:

```
Just (3 + (5+))
```

You're adding a number to a function! This is why you get weird type errors.

Specifically, Haskell is trying desperately to pretend `(5+)` is a number:

```
b :: (Num (a -> a), Num a) => Maybe (a -> a)
```

It's saying, ***if*** there is some crazy type `a` for which `a` and `(a -> a)` are both instances of `Num`, I could add them together inside the Functor as though they were numbers, and give you a resulting `Maybe (a -> a)`! Generally, however, functions aren't instances of the `Num` typeclass, so everything blows up.

You meant to write:

```
let b = ((3+).) <$> Just (5+)
```

Which indeed works as you expected (`b <*> Just 1 == Just 9`).

Comment: That, or `($3) <$> Just (5+)`

Comment: There's a subtle difference: the OP said they wanted `b` (and `c`) to equal `Just ((3+) . (5+))`, which has the type `Num a => Maybe (a -> a)`, not `Num a => Maybe a`.

Comment: He said he expected them to be like that, I'm not sure that's what he actually wanted.

Comment: @Mauris. Thanks for the explanation. `fmap (3+) (5+) 1 = 9` and since `fmap f Just a` is defined as `Just f a` I thought Haskell would give me something line `Just (3+) ((5+))` and when I call that on 1 I get `Just ((3+) ((5+) 1))` and get Just 9. But then again Haskell does not use parentheses for function inputs. **BTW Cubic** Sorry if the questions were not clear but I did want `b` and `c` to equal `Just ((3+) . (5+))`

Comment: Be careful with your parentheses: `Just f a` is (probably) a type error. You want `Just (f a)`.

Comment: @ClayThomas yes that's what I meant to type. the `Just (3+) ((5+))` should also be `Just ((3+) ((5+)))` even though such thing makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: There's a difference between `(3+)(5+)` and `(3+).(5+)`. The latter is composition of functions; the former is *applying* `(3+)` to `(5+)` (which causes the really confusing type errors you ran into).